# Visual Studion 2015 and Angular2 Beta 2 dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

My environment is VS2015 with TypeScript 1.7.3, Angular2 Beta 2, target ECMA 5. I've modified the csproj file to include  `TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators = true`.

I'm working on the Angular2 [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) and can not get dependency injection working as documented.  I can only get DI to work when I include `@Inject` in the `AppComponent` class constructor. If I don't include `@Inject` I receive this error -

> EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for AppComponent(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

I did not include the code in this post because its the same as the tutorial. I did try modifying boot.ts as follows:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HeroService]);
```

but I still get the error. Has anyone else run into this?

The `HeroService` is decorated with `@Injectable`:

```
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';
import {Injectable} from '../node_modules/angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    heroes: Hero[];

    getHeroes() {
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }
   //  See the "Take it slow" appendix
    getHeroesSlowly() {
        return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
            setTimeout(() => resolve(HEROES), 2000) // 2 seconds
        );
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '../node_modules/angular2/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
        <h2>My Heroes</h2>
        <ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes" 
                (click)="onSelect(hero)" 
                [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
                <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>      
        `
    ,directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
    ,providers: [HeroService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    public heroes: Hero[];
    public selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) { 
   // constructor( @Inject(HeroService) private _heroService: HeroService) {

    }
    getHeroes() {
        this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }
    onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Comment: If you pass `HeroService` in `bootstrap()` you don't need it in `providers` in your `AppComponent`. This can lead to several instances being created while you probably only want one.

Comment: I tried both ways and got the same error. Because DI works when I specify Inject it seems like the VS TypeScript compiler isn't generating the metadata for the Injectable decorator.

Comment: I can't help you with such TS configuration issues. I'm a Dart-only developer.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the following to the csproj file and was able to remove the @Inject from the code -   <TypeScriptAdditionalFlags> $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags) --emitDecoratorMetadata </TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the following to the csproj file and was able to remove the @Inject from the code -

```
<TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>true</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
```

See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Setting-Compiler-Options-in-MSBuild-projects) for how to set TS compiler options in Visual Studio